# Display 3 Gantt Charts of a Prj Task

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, gantt-chart

I am a newbie of sharepoint 2007. And I am just a site admin.

Suppose I have a prj site, which I have to define 3 group of dates to Prj Task like the following
 - Original Start/End Date
 - Current Start/End Date
 - Actual Start/End Date
However, with the default Gantt View setting, I can only to set one date group to have displayed in Gantt. Is there any method to have it done?

Thanks

Comment: You mean Gantt Charts?  (I edited but then I saw it spelled that way three times, so I thought I might ask instead.)

Comment: Yes.. Gantt Charts.. I always misspell it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest create 3 views with different dates thats the MAX you can achieve through OOTB feature